# macOS on qemu-kvm using Clover

Tags: macos, ubuntu, bootloader

I am trying to install macOS using qemu-kvm following [this article](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-macos-on-kvm-qemu/) step by step. I am executing all the steps from a Ubuntu 20.4 machine. After I run the `./basic.sh`, it pops a new window, but I do not have the option Boot macOS Install from macOS Base System.

Clover screenshot:
[image: Clover screenshot]

Did someone else encountered this before?

Comment: MacOS virtualization is not supported here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: Understood, didn't knew this detail. You can close the question.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is not, nor has it ever been, illegal to run Mac OS(X) in a VM (or PC hardware) for one's own purposes. This is quite frankly a myth that has been perpetuated by people who simply do not understand what an EULA can actually and legally stipulate (all Apple can really do is deny support), as well as conflate it with companies who tried selling PCs with Mac OS(X) pre-installed who did have real legal action taken against them.
  
So no, there is no "legal grey area" here as far as running it for personal use.